# Macro to add two amounts based on a common id

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook with three sheets.  I'm trying to create a macro that matches an id on two sheets, sums an amount from another column on that sheet, and populate the result on the third sheet.

Example:
Sheet 1

> id,   amount
>   1, 10
>   2, 13
>   3, 7
>   4, 33
>   5,16

Sheet 2

> id, amount
>   1, 3
>   3, 40
>   4, 12

Expected Return on sheet 3

> id, amount
>   1, 13
>   2, 13
>   3, 47
>   4, 45
>   5,16

Comment: Is there a particular reason for using VBA for this? Formulas should do and are probably easier to maintain going forward.

Comment: So which exact part of this are you having a problem with?  What have you tried, and what problems did you run into?

Comment: I really need vba because the example above is very simplified.  There is actually 10,000 rows of data and 9 columns to add.

Answer (score 0):

On sheet 3 in A1

```
`=index(Sheet1!B1:B10,Match(A1,Sheet1!A1:A10))+index(Sheet2!B1:B10,Match(A1,Sheet2!A1:A10))'
```

This will search for the id in column a of sheet 3 on sheet 1 and 2 and bring back the values from column b on those sheets

Comment: if using vba you would have to use a loop to look through the cells in sheet 1 and 2 and then a if function to return the value in column b if the id is matched. The formula is a much easier solution